# My window won't show up

Tags: python

Hi I am doing this Tkinter assignment and i don't know why it won't run even when i put the mainloop in it.

```
# Importing Tkinter to display the graphics
import Tkinter

# Creating a class called StoryMaker
class StoryMaker:
    # The initializer with the self parameter
    def __init__(self):
        # This creates the main window
        self.main_window = Tkinter.Tk()

        # This creates the three different frames for different widgets
        self.top_frame = Tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.mid_frame = Tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.bottom_frame = Tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)

        # Instructs the user to enter the information given to create the story
        self.story_label = Tkinter.Label (self.top_frame, text = "Please enter the information given for the new story, then click the \"Make Story\" Button!" )
        self.prompt_label1 = Tkinter.Label (self.top_frame, text = "Character Name: ")
        self.get_prompt1 = Tkinter.Entry (self.top_frame, width = 10)

        self.story_label.pack (side = 'left')
        story.prompt_label.pack (side = 'left')
        self.get_prompt1.pack (side = 'left')

        self.prompt_label2 = Tkinter.Label (self.mid_frame, text = "Place: ")
        self.get_prompt2 = Tkinter.Entry (self.mid_frame, width = 10)

        self.prompt_label3 = Tkinter.Label (self.mid_frame, text = "Food: ")
        self.get_prompt3 = Tkinter.Entry (self.mid_frame, width = 10)

        self.radio_var = Tkinter.IntVar()
        self.radio_var.set(1)

        self.prompt_label4 = Tkinter.Label(self.mid_frame, text = "Hotels")
        self.rb1 = Tkinter.Radiobutton(self.mid_frame, text = "Hilton", variable = self.radio_var, value = 1)
        self.rb2 = Tkinter.Radiobutton(self.mid_frame, text = "Burj Al Arab", variable = self.radio_var, value = 2)
        self.rb3 = Tkinter.Radiobutton(self.mid_frame, text = "Holiday Inn", variable = self.radio_var, value = 3)

        self.rb1.pack()
        self.rb2.pack()
        self.rb3.pcak()

        self.cb_var1 = Tkinter.IntVar()
        self.cb_var2 = Tkinter.IntVar()
        self.cb_var3 = Tkinter.IntVar()

        self.cb_var1.set(0)
        self.cb_var2.set(0)
        self.cb_var3.set(0)

        self.prompt_label5 = Tkinter.Label (self.mid_frame, text = "Foods")
        self.cb1 = Tkinter.Checkbutton (self.top_frame, text = "Pizza", variable = self.cb_var1)
        self.cb2 = Tkinter.Checkbutton (self.top_frame, text = "Spaghetti", variable = self.cb_var2)
        self.cb3 = Tkinter.Checkbutton (self.top_frame, text = "Hamburger", variable = self.cb_var3)

        self.cb1.pack()
        self.cb2.pack()
        self.cb3.pack()

        self.create_button = Tkinter.Button(self.bottom_frame, text = "Create", command = self.story)
        self.quit_button = Tkinter.Button(self.bottom_frame, text = "Quit", command = self.main_window.quit)

        self.create_button.pack(side = 'left')
        self.quit_button.pack(side = 'left')

        self.top_frame.pack()
        self.mid_frame.pack()
        self.bottom_frame.pack()

        Tkinter.mainloop()

my_gui = StoryMaker
```

Comment: Are you getting any error message? If so, what?

Answer (score 1):

You last line should actually **call** the class you just spent all that time constructing:

```
my_gui = StoryMaker()
```

See how that works for you. Doing this will execute the special `__init__()` method, and run your GUI.